# Embedding bold font as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder

I am having trouble embedding a font as bold using FB4.  I am using TextLayout fields and TextLayoutFormat to do this and my code is as follows:

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.AntiAliasType;
import flash.text.Font;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.engine.FontLookup;

import flashx.textLayout.container.ContainerController;
import flashx.textLayout.elements.ParagraphElement;
import flashx.textLayout.elements.SpanElement;
import flashx.textLayout.elements.TextFlow;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.TextLayoutFormat;

public class FontEmbedding extends Sprite
{
    [Embed(source='TAHOMA.ttf', fontName='Tahoma', embedAsCFF="true")]
    private var _fontTahoma:Class;
    private const TAHOMA:String = "Tahoma";

    [Embed(source='TAHOMA.ttf', fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD, fontName='Tahoma Bold', embedAsCFF="true")]
    private var _fontTahomBold:Class;
    private const TAHOMA_BOLD:String = "Tahoma Bold";

    public function FontEmbedding()
    {           
        this.textLayout();
    }

    private function textLayout():void
    {
        var textLayoutFormat:TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
        textLayoutFormat.fontLookup = FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF;
        textLayoutFormat.fontFamily = TAHOMA_BOLD;
        textLayoutFormat.fontSize = 32;

        var textFlow:TextFlow = new TextFlow();
        var paragraphElement:ParagraphElement = new ParagraphElement();
        textFlow.addChild(paragraphElement);

        var span:SpanElement = new SpanElement();
        span.text = "This is an example";
        paragraphElement.addChild(span);

        textFlow.format = textLayoutFormat;

        var containerController:ContainerController = new     ContainerController(this, 400, 100);
        textFlow.flowComposer.addController(containerController);
        textFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();
    }
}
}
```

The font just displays as normal and the `'fontWeight'` property is ignored.  Any ideas would be gratefully received?

Comment: Isn't it called fontFamily="Tahoma" ??

Comment: Just a guess but that filename 'GillSansforJL-Light' would indicate a set of glyphs that are not bold to me. What does the ttf look like in a preview application?

Comment: This might help you debug. It will show the fonts that you have embedded.
var embeddedFonts:Array = Font.enumerateFonts(false);
embeddedFonts.sortOn("fontName", Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);
trace("Embedded Fonts:");
for (var i:int = 0; i < embeddedFonts.length; i++ ) {
 trace("fontName: " + (embeddedFonts[i] as Font).fontName + ", fontStyle: " + (embeddedFonts[i] as Font).fontStyle);
}

Comment: @Hawks this is just an example but in my real app I will need to make the standard Tahoma font bold from the Windows/Font folder, is this not possible?

The fonts with bold font style are showing after implementing Trevors code, so I am not sure why it's not displaying as bold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me, with the line `textLayoutFormat.fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD;` or not.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.AntiAliasType;
    import flash.text.Font;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.engine.FontLookup;
    import flash.text.engine.FontWeight;

    import flashx.textLayout.container.ContainerController;
    import flashx.textLayout.elements.ParagraphElement;
    import flashx.textLayout.elements.SpanElement;
    import flashx.textLayout.elements.TextFlow;
    import flashx.textLayout.formats.TextLayoutFormat;

    public class FontEmbedding extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source='ChaparralPro-Bold.otf', fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD, fontName='ChaparralPro-Bold', embedAsCFF="true")]
        private var _fontGillSans:Class;
        private const FONT_CHAP:String = "ChaparralPro-Bold";

        public function FontEmbedding()
        {           
            this.textLayout();
        }

        private function textLayout():void
        {
            var textLayoutFormat:TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
            textLayoutFormat.fontLookup = FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF;
            textLayoutFormat.fontFamily = FONT_CHAP;
            textLayoutFormat.fontSize = 32;
            textLayoutFormat.fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD;

            var textFlow:TextFlow = new TextFlow();
            var paragraphElement:ParagraphElement = new ParagraphElement();
            textFlow.addChild(paragraphElement);

            var span:SpanElement = new SpanElement();
            span.text = "This is an example";
            paragraphElement.addChild(span);

            textFlow.format = textLayoutFormat;

            var containerController:ContainerController = new     ContainerController(this, 400, 100);
            textFlow.flowComposer.addController(containerController);
            textFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you clarify that adding 'fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD' emboldened the font? It looks like a bold font anyway.

Comment: From my experience (I developed and maintain an online designer that uses about 100 fonts) even though a font is bold you often still have to set it to bold for it to render correctly. I made a set of scripts to convert font files into classes and then compile them here http://blog.alastairdawson.com/2009/06/30/automate-font-compiling-for-flex-with-ruby/

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I needed to change 'Tahoma.tff' to 'TahomaBD.tff'.  This font doesn't display in the windows fonts folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely an issue with applying **Bold** type font.

The font is not set as BOLD with following code, if you dynamically update the text later on somewhere in the code.

```
var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myTextFormat.font = "Arial";
myTextFormat.bold = true;
myTextField.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);

//
myTextField.text = "some dynamic text";
```

Instead, you need to apply the text format each time you update the text.

```
var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myTextFormat.font = "Arial";
myTextFormat.bold = true;

//
myTextField.text = "some dynamic text";
myTextField.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
```

But, i generally set it as default font as shown below,

```
var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myTextFormat.font = "Arial";
myTextFormat.bold = true;
myTextField.defaultTextFormat = myTextFormat;

//
myTextField.text = "some dynamic text";
```

Not a perfect way for robust project but it works.

Report this issue on,
[bugs.adobe.com](http://bugs.adobe.com/)

Answer (score -1):

```
var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myFormat.color = 0x000000;
myFormat.font = "Arial Bold";
myFormat.bold = true;
txt.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
```

Comment: Please edit your answer, explaining why this is a good solution.